# CSS how to hide resize divs while keeping it centerd

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am developing Facebook application (I am not CSS pro.). The iframe canvas is liquid eg. width 100%.

The main div that hold the application is 500 px wide. There are two divs of left and right from main dic (see picture below). Left and right divs must have the same width.

When user resize browser window I want keep main div centered with fixed width while both left and right divs must resize appropriately to take only available space.

In case there is no space for left and right divs they must disappear. Main div must be centered.

[image]

Thank you very much for you help.

```
</style>
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#main{
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
#left, #right{
  width: calc(50% - 150px);
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) { 
  #left, #right{
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div id="left">1</div><div id="main">2</div><div id="right">3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/clicker314/L77jh8ak/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the calc() CSS function, this problem is relatively easy to solve:

```
#main{
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#left, #right{
  width: calc(50% - 250px);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thus, the left and right divs adjust their height based on the width of half of the screen, minus half of the main element. If you want a fallback, add another 'width:' rule on the line prior to the calc() width rule.

This works on all modern browsers, including IE 10+. If you want IE 8/9 support, add the second width rule I mentioned above.

For IE 8/9 support, you have two options:
1. Give a defined width for those two options. I.e. #left, #right{width: 200px;}. 
2. Add some JS/jQuery to imitate the CSS calc() function.

To hide the divs on a certain size, add a media query (the 600px I added is hypothetical, pick any minimum screen size you like):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
  #left, #right{
    display: none;
  }
  #main{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The #main rule there is optional. It assumes that you want the #main div to take up all of the space available in the container.

Comment: Great stuff! I didn't know about calc! Now I have to learn how to hide that and I am fine! Thank you!

Comment: Still don't know who to handle IE8/9 =)

Comment: Thank you @saesris! You are awesome! Check out this link: http://jsfiddle.net/clicker314/L77jh8ak/4/ It really works!!!

Comment: I will go with jQuery )) I am coder, jQuery is easier for me =) Thank you very much!